# PerfConsole and Visual Studio 2008 Team System Profiler

Tags: visual-studio-2008, profiler

Does the [PerfConsole](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2006/08/04/688599.aspx) work with the output from the VS 2008 Team System Profiler output? (.vsp files)

When I try and run 'load' on the output file I get an error message:

```
"Couldn't match to either expected sampled or instrumented profile schema,  defaulting to sampled"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although PerfConsole output this error message, but it still should work fine, do you get failures loading the rest of the profile?